# I am not getting the value from the database

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am using MVT in django. I am using generic CBV (listview, detailview). here are my codes

**Here is model.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Singers(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=256)
    age= models.IntegerField()
    gender= models.CharField(max_length=10)


class Albums(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=256)
    singer=models.ForeignKey(Singers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**view.py**

```
from django.views import generic
from core.models import Albums, Singers

#in generic view instead of functions, we use classes

class AlbumView(generic.ListView):
    model = Albums
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Albums.objects.all()

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Albums
    template_name = 'detailview.html'
```

**Here are urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from core.views import AlbumView, DetailView
urlpatterns = [
    path('album/', AlbumView.as_view()),
    path('album/detail/<pk>/', DetailView.as_view())
]
```

**Here is index.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <h2>Albums</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for albums in object_list %}
            <li>{{ albums.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**here is detailview.html**

```
{% block content %}
  <h1>name: {{Albums.name}}</h1>
  <p><strong>Singer: {{Albums.Singer}}</strong></p>
{% endblock %}
```

The detail view is not working fine. It is not fetching the respective name of the album and singer details.

Suggest me what should i do?

Comment: In `detailview.html`, change `Album` to just `object`, so for example instead of `{{Albums.name}}`, use `{{ object.name }}`

Comment: Then it is displaying a blank page. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
{% block content %}
  <h1>name: {{object.name}}</h1>
  <p><strong>Singer: {{object.singer.name}}</strong></p>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Albums
    template_name = 'detailview.html'
```

This is not working you have to get first context like this

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        // Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        // Add in a QuerySet of all the books
        context['Album_list'] = Albums.objects.all()
        return context
```

And you can do as well

```
context_object_name = 'publisher'
queryset = Publisher.objects.all()
```